# Read keys from Properties file into array

Tags: java

I have an application that I have been working on. This application is configurable via a Properties file, from which it gets most of its variables.

This application is a survey, with the potential of any number of questions.

The questions are stored as an array, where the max index is equal to the number of questions.

I have tried the following:

```
for(int noOfQuestToSet = 0; noOfQuestToSet<noOfQuest; noOfQuestToSet++)
        {
            String[] questionArr = new String[noOfQuestToSet];
            questionArr = props.getProperty("Q" + noOfQuestToSet).toString();
        }
```

The idea is the loop will use an integer to compare to the number of emails `noOfEmails` variable (read from the properties file). The Question key syntax is `Q1=<question>`.

The loop should use an integer set to 0, compare it to the number of questions and append the number each increment to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int noOfQuestToSet = 1; noOfQuestToSet<=noOfQuest; noOfQuestToSet++)
            {
                int i = noOfQuestToSet -1;
                questionArr = new String[noOfQuestToSet];
                String appendToIndex = String.valueOf(noOfQuestToSet);
                questionArr[i] = props.getProperty("Q"+appendToIndex);

                String[] answers= new String[noOfQuestToSet];
                do
                {
                    Scanner scnAnswer = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n");
                    System.out.println(questionArr[i]);
                    answers[i] = scnAnswer.next();
                    if(iCheckAnswerforNull(answers, i)==true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please ensure you enter an answer to each question");
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.println(finalMess);
                    //EmailSend sendEmail = new EmailSend();
                //  EmailSend.sendEmail(userName, answers);
                    break;
                }
                while(true);
            }
```

After a little tinkering and a shunt in the right direction from @meister_reineke, here is the working loop to get the property and append it to an array (without using ArrayLists:

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain more, what you are up to, and what your variables are.
What are the emails there for? and what is the Question key syntax? and how does getProterty() work.
and finally, what do you want to achieve? if you want an array with all the questions in it could look like this:

```
String[] questionArr=new String[noOfQuestToSet];
for (int i=0;i<noOfQuest;i++){
    questionArr[i]=props.getProperty("Q"+i).toString();
}
```

If you dont know the exact number of questions in advance, use a List (ArrayList, or LinkedList) where you can add a string anytime without knowing the final size of the list.

plz read the guidelines for asking questions

Comment: Whenever I rune my application I get a NullPointerException thrown, I don't suppose you have a solution for this?

Comment: plz chek the green mark "correct answer" on the left below the "useful Answer" counter. where is your Exception thrown?

Comment: It's thrown here ` questionArr[i]=props.getProperty("Q"+i).toString();`
It's because no field exists with the key `Q0` or `Qi` at a guess.

Comment: Post your getProperty-class in a new question. as a first idea, tell your getproperty to return an empty string, if Qi does not exist. then at last no exception is thrown.

Comment: I found the solution, see my answer.

Comment: your solution produces a nearly empty Array! You need to put the      String[] questionArr = new String[noOfQuestToSet]; outside of the for-loop!

Comment: The array is populated within the loop, I'll amend my answer to show the full loop.